# Script to generate primary key in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

We are migrating our database to AWS, but they are asking us to have a primary key in all tables present in the database.

We have around 50 tables in our database which are added by our installer, but we do not have any primary key. So we need to add a column in each table as that tables primary key, and populate it with an unique value.

Any help on writing this script which will loop through all tables in the database, add a column and populate it with primary key.

Thanks in advance. 
I got SQL to update single table just need a way to loop through all tables in the DB:

```
ALTER TABLE TextEntity ADD TextEntity_id BIGINT IDENTITY;
GO
ALTER TABLE TextEntity
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TextEntity_id PRIMARY KEY (TextEntity_id);
GO
```

Comment: Primary key should not be randomly selected..you have to choose a good key which helps

Comment: in each tables case we can start from 1

Comment: "We have around 50 tables in the our database which are added by our installer but we do not have any primary key. So we need to generate add a column in each table as that tables primary key and generate that with unique primary key." **Absolutely not!** Don't add a surrogate key to every table. Instead, figure out what are the tables *natural* keys are and make them your primary key, or at least a unique index. Surrogate keys do have their place, but if you are just randomly adding them to tables that have no natural keys, you destroy your database's ability to of referential integrity.

Comment: This is just for the purpose of migration we need to do, once we migrate it to AWS we gonna drop them all. the problem we are facing while migrating is some of data is getting lost if the table dose not have primary key. AWS team asked us to do so.

Comment: You need bigint for all your tables?

Comment: Not really, but keeping in mind that some have millions of record i out that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQL Server metadata tables to fetch a list of the tables you want to edit, then create dynamic SQL that adds the new column as an identity and the primary key:

```
DECLARE @script nvarchar(max)=''    --contains the dynamic TSQL code
DECLARE @table_schema varchar(max); --contains the name of your schema
DECLARE @table_name varchar(max);   --contains the name of your table
DECLARE @key_Cursor as CURSOR;      --cursor that will loop on your tables

--Here you must add a condition in the where clause that filters only 
--the 50 tables you want to edit
SET @key_Cursor = CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_CATALOG='primary_keys' and TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE';

OPEN @key_Cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM @key_Cursor INTO @table_schema, @table_name;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            --create the script that adds a new identity column called ID
            set @script=' alter table ' + @table_schema + '.' + @table_name + ' add id int identity(1,1); '

            --add the code that create the primary key using the new ID column 
            set @script = @script + ' ALTER TABLE ' + @table_schema + '.' + @table_name + ' ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_' + @table_name + '_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC); '

            --execute the script for the current table
            exec sp_executesql   @script  

            --print (@script)

            --fetch data for the next table
            FETCH NEXT FROM @key_Cursor INTO @table_schema, @table_name;
        END
CLOSE @key_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE @key_Cursor;
```

This is only a draft script just to show you how to loop on tables: it works but it is vulnerable to SQL injection. Consider using a parametrized query.

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space.

Comment: Aside: The code always adds a column named `id`. A more general approach would check the `COLUMNS` metadata to avoid colliding with an existing column of the same name. In the event of a collision it could start working through an Elbonian telephone directory trying names. (It isn't clear what the usefulness of an unpredictably named primary key column is, but it seems to meet the OP's needs.) Adding a test for an existing primary key would probably be a good reality check. If a PK is found there is no need to worry, it will be dropped after the migration.

Answer (score 3):

something like below?

```
select CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', QUOTENAME(name, '[]'), ' ADD PK_', name, ' int identity(1, 1) Primary Key')
from sys.tables
```

or you can try sp_msforeachtable to populate primary key

Comment: I got the SQL for one table ALTER TABLE TextEntity ADD TextEntity_id BIGINT IDENTITY;
GO
ALTER TABLE TextEntity
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TextEntity_id PRIMARY KEY (TextEntity_id);
GO  - just need someway to loop thorough all tables in the DB

Comment: @MayurRandive, you're missing the point. This solution generates all of the ALTER TABLE statements for you. You just have to copy, paste, and execute them. Is it a loop? No, Does it fix your problem? Yes. In some ways, a down and dirty solution like this seems like a perfect way to execute something you shouldn't be doing at all.